# How to find and to remove string resources with duplicate values

Tags: android, string

What i mean:

```
<string name="str1">That is a string</string>
<string name="str2">That is a string</string>
```

Both strings have the same value, so one of them is in most cases redundant.

Is there the way to find and to remove such string resources with duplicate values in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a parser to do it yourself.  The file should be valid xml, so it should not be too difficult to do with the various tools available to you.

DOM,
SAX,
StAX just to name a few.

Comment: yes, i did it ... using vba in excel. But i thought, that maybe there is a ready solution for that.

Comment: That is pretty specific functionality.  I do not see the real need for an implementation of it.

Answer (score 0):

use lint command, it will provide you list of duplicates, errors, warnings, optimization, against your ui resources.
simple type lint %project_path%

**edit**
lint is found in the sdk directory tools subdirectory. In Android Studio, at least, You can find your sdk directory by looking for the sdk.dir property in your project's local.properties file in your project root.